# SproutForms: "an unknown error occurred" in entries template chart

Tags: plugins, plugin-sproutforms

When viewing the charts in the entries template of the SproutForms plugin, I receive an "an unknown error occurred" error message.

In the console, I see this:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error): https://domain.com/index.php?p=admin/actions/sproutForms/charts/getEntriesData

Any clue what's going on here?

Comment: If it's a Craft/SproutForms generate 500 ISE, then the underlying error message will be logged in `craft/storage/runtime/logs`.

Comment: I actually tailed those logs, and nothing was logged when I repeatedly encountered the error. Very strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: This issue has been fixed in Sprout Forms v2.3.0, which also added Entry Status workflows and support for front-end Entries, Categories, and Tags relations fields ;-)

--

The issue you’re running into with the Sprout Forms chart is due to your PHP version.  We have it on our list and it should be fixed in the next release.  Until we get that release, the way to fix the issue is to upgrade your PHP version to something higher than PHP 5.4

Comment: I have php version 5.6 but still . The error message still prompting in my screen and it's so annoying, any way to prevent that happening ?

Comment: @lancedelacruz Can you send us a support request and provide more information about your setup (version of Craft, version of Sprout Forms, etc), logs, and your database if you can share it. This is not a widespread issue so we'll need more info about your environment to help track this down: https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/request/support

Comment: I already did. I'm hoping for an answer because i'm struggling right now, though it doesn't affect the performance of the page, i have doubt that maybe in future, it will affect.